# Delphi BluetoothLE WriteCharacteristic Access Violation

Tags: delphi, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

This is Delphi 10.1 Berlin (probably unpatched).
**This code is pretty basic.**
***This code is not stable.***

Why?

```
procedure TBLEEnumerator.WriteToSubScribedCharacteristic(bs: TArray<byte>);
var
  //member ble is an instance of TBluetoothLE
  chr: TBluetoothGattCharacteristic;
begin
  chr := ble.GetCharacteristic(FBLEGattService, ChooseCharacteristic);
  chr.SetValue(bs);
  ble.WriteCharacteristic(self.dev, chr);
end;
```

A few other notes:
This error is when running on Windows, but I intend this code to run also on mobile devices.

This function is called from the Main Thread and is a wrapper around the TBluetoothLE component.  The original connection/scan is also handled from the main thread.

It is pretty simple, obviously.  TArray is a reference-counted dynamic array.

Here's the call stack when it tanks:

```
:761d31ce ucrtbase.memcpy + 0x4e
System.Win.BluetoothWinRT.BytesToIBuffer(???,???)
System.Win.BluetoothWinRT.TWinRTBluetoothGattCharacteristic.SetValueToDevice
System.Win.BluetoothWinRT.TWinRTBluetoothLEDevice.DoWriteCharacteristic$52$ActRec.$0$Body
System.Classes.TAnonymousThread.Execute
System.Classes.ThreadProc($7511F40)
System.ThreadWrapper($5A30D30)
:740162c4 KERNEL32.BaseThreadInitThunk + 0x24
:77060fd9 ; 
:77060fa4 ;
```

Comment: You've declared `chr` as a local, set its value, but then pass `self.chr` to `WriteCharacteristic`.  Your local `chr` seems to be hiding a field of the same name, but you seem to be confusing their use... Is that on purpose?  Maybe `self.chr` is `nil`... if you declared it but haven't used it for anything?  I think this needs a [mcve].  A little debugging wouldn't go amiss either... is `self.chr` assigned when `ble.WriteCharacteristic` is called?

Comment: According to the call stack, your code runs in an anonymous thread, it is quite likely that your code is not thread safe.

Comment: The self.chr was a good observation.  However it was not a fix.  I moved chr to be local after seeing this instability when using it as a member... but obviously I forgot to change one part.   The application still crashes.

Comment: Here's my theory.  The "anonymous thread" that is mentioned in the call stack is not my own.  It is  created in the System.Win.BluetoothWinRT unit.


Now check out this function signature for BytesToIBuffer().... function BytesToIBuffer(const ABytes: TBytes; AOffset: Integer = 0): IBuffer;

Const ABytes:Tbyte in an anonymous thread?  Passing a const string/dynamic array forgoes reference counting.  The TBytes array could be getting destroyed before this anonymous array finishes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the deal.  This is a BUG in the Embarcadero Libraries.  Yes, Yet another bug that they will probably never fix.

Here's how to fix it for yourself:

1. copy System.Win.BluetoothWinRT.pas to your project directory or some other path used by the project.
2. open the file in the IDE.
3. Search for "BytestoIBuffer".
4. Remove the word "const" from the function signature.

Very few people seem to realize this (including the authors of FMX and VCL) but the use of "const" strings and dynamic arrays causes the Win32 compiler to optimize-out the reference count handling for those structures.  I don't know if it affects the mobile compilers or the Win64 compiler, but maybe.

The nasty effect of this is that if that string or dynamic array originated from another thread, that other thread might very well decide to destroy that string or dynamic array before the new thread (in this case an anonymous thread created to write-behind the data) is finished working with it.

Removing const from this function fixed the instability.

Comment: That sounds like the wrong fix. There shouldn't be two parties holding references to the same object. That can lead to a data race. FWIW const has the same impact on ref counting for all compilers. And what you say doesn't ring true. Surely this class needs to take a reference at some point in order for the thread Execute method to be able to refer to it. All in all I remain to be convinced. Did you submit a bug report?

Comment: @J... I don't see how the `Execute` method of a thread can access the array without its reference count being increased. Surely somewhere there must be a variable that the thread can access, and when that variable was assigned the ref count must have been increased.

Comment: The anonymous thread does not hold a reference to the variable anywhere because the only real reference is passed as a const in an anonymous function.  Once it gets to BytesToIBuffer, the reference count is ignored and nobody checks or waits on the anonymous thread to complete its work... so for all we know it could need that buffer for 1ms or 10000ms.  In the meantime, the calling thread is totally free to come in and do whatever it wants with that buffer and is completely unaware of the background process accessing this part of memory.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the accepted solution is correct.  Think of what might happen, for example, if the anonymous thread spent 10 or more seconds processing BytesToIBuffer.  No one checks or waits on this thread, ANYWHERE in the code (BAD BAD DESIGN).  Fire-forget threads are virtually NEVER a good idea and I correct these kinds of mistakes all the time among my colleagues.  That buffer may have a 0 reference count after it is passed to BytesToIBuffer().  There is nothing preventing such a scenario because the reference count is off by one when passed as **const**

Comment: Surely the solution is to hold a reference rather than to force all users of that function to perform ref counting

Comment: Well a potentially "higher performance" solution would be to keep and hold a non-const variable reference in the anonymous function that is not released until BytesToIBuffer has finished.  This would, of course, require every instance of this to be changed.  Being a performance snob myself, I might opt for this kind of a solution for something where I need high throughput, but this is BLE which tops out at about 35000 baud if you're lucky.  Fixing it my way requires just the deletion of one word in the interface and implementation sections.

Comment: Also forces you to recompile all units that use that one. The other way lets you change just the implementation sections and so minimise the RTL recompilation demands. Anyway, you seem well on top of this.